# How to open Chrome with defined tabs?

Tags: macos, shell, sh

I'm quite new in .sh, I'm wonder how to open e.g.: Chrome web browser with two tabs, let's say that can be 'google.com' and 'yahoo.com'. So far I find out how to simply open 'Chrome' but I can't find how to force opening tabs in it.

I would be grateful if someone would gave me some hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On OS X, use the `open` CLI:

```
open -a 'Google Chrome' http://www.example.org http://google.com
```

Note that the protocol specifier (`http://`) is mandatory.